# WebP library for Java?

Tags: library, java, images, image-processing

Is there a library in java for producing/consuming image files in the WebP format? The libraries I found online are either [libwebp](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/download) written in C, or its JNI bindings in Java. Is there anything in pure Java?

Comment: Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861601/webp-library-for-java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[TwelveMonkeys ImageIO](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys) now has full ImageIO read support for WebP (lossy, lossless and lossy + lossless alpha) modes.

---

Another free option is the ImageIO plugin from [Java VP8 Decoder](https://sourceforge.net/p/javavp8decoder/code/ci/master/tree/src/net/sf/javavp8decoder/imageio/). It contains a Java implementation of the VP8 codec.

Another candidate is [JCodec](http://jcodec.org/), which have Java VP8 encoding and decoding, but no ImageIO plugin, as far as I can see.

As correctly pointed out by the OP, the VP8 key frame encoding is the method used in WebP for *lossy encoding* only. The format also specifies *lossless* encoding, and a combination of lossy RGB + lossless alpha. The above projects does *not* implement any of these.

Comment: Sorry that I'm not familiar with WebP. Is VP8 equivalent to WebP? From [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/compression), *VP8 key frame encoding* is only one way to encode the WebP image. There is also *WebP lossless encoding*.

Comment: Looking forward for lossless and extended (lossy + lossless alpha) modes!

Answer (score 1):

[JDeli](https://www.idrsolutions.com/jdeli/) can read/write WebP format and many others, but it isn't free.

Answer (score 1):

[Scrimage](https://github.com/sksamuel/scrimage) can do this, through delegation to the google binaries (which are included in the distribution).