# Animated WebP decoder for Java

Tags: java, offline, image-conversion, png, file-conversion

I am looking for a good Java library that can decode animated WebP imgaes to PNG files for each frame. I have come across libraries such as JMagick, webp-imageio, and JDeli, but these libraries are either hard to implement, outdated, or locked behind paywalls. I know a similar question already exists on [this thread](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/47212/webp-library-for-java), but I want to decode animated WebP files such as [this image](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/animated-webp-supported.webp). Additionally, I would rather not rely on calls to web APIs, even though such web APIs acomplish this task already. Thanks in advance for the help.